# Icons constantly changes to "generic" one

Tags: macos, finder, icon, bug

After updating to one of the recent versions of Ventura, I have faced a bug that happens about half of the time I edit and save `txt` files.

The bug is that the icon of a file become "generic". For example, I have a file with six lines of text about using AppStore.

Here is how its icon looks normally:

[image]

And after I save it, it often changes to:

[image]

The current workaround to restore the "normal" icon is to rename the file, e.g. from `appstore` to `appstore1` and then back to `appstore`. But after a week this really makes me angry. How to fix this?

Comment: This looks like the QuickLook preview icon is not available. Does QuickLook work (press SPACE)? Also: do the files have the .txt file extension (and have you hidden it in the Finder)?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, they have an extension. Yes, when I press the Space key, Quick View works fine. I have also tried to remove the icon cache as shown here: https://gist.github.com/ismyrnow/e92c6010cda9325b2d8811387a05f224. This didn't help. And I also tried to reinstall Ventura. This also didn't help. After I edit and save a file, its icon may (or may not) be changed to a generic one, either immediately or when I re-visit the folder. The issue also happens with other plain text file formats. I remember the same issue with CSS files.

Comment: Are you using TextEdit, or another app? What model of Mac is this? It may just be being slow to create the preview. Have you tried turning OFF, and then ON the "Show Icon Preview" setting in the Finder's View Options?

Comment: Yes, I use TextEdit for them. No other apps are running, and my Mac is quite powerful, it is MacBook Pro with M1 Pro chip. As I said, if I rename the file, the icon immediately changed to the correct one. Another way to fix icons is to restart Finder. That is to say, I am absolutely sure this bug is  not caused by  performance reasons.

Comment: What is interesting is that this bug affects only plain text files, that is, for example, `.txt` and `.md`, and doesn't affect Pages documents or images.